# Prove that $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

> Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a Hausdorff topological space $X$. Prove that $X/G$ is Hausdorff. Deduce that the projective space $P^n$ is Hausdorff for all $n$.

My Try:

Consider the quotient projection $p:X\rightarrow X/G$. Let $Gx\neq Gy$. Then, $x\neq y$. There exists neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$, such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$. $p$ is an open map. So, I was going to prove that $p(U)\cap p(V)=\emptyset$. But, in order to prove it, I need to have $p^{-1}(p(U))=U$ and $p^{-1}(p(V))=V$. But, I could not prove it. My question is, is it true? Then how may I prove it? Moreover, I am confused with $P^n$ here. What is it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to use that the fibres of $p$ are finite.

Comment: The result is false unless the group acts freely. [Look at the first counterexample.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/50050/10014)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: What do you mean by fibres of $p$?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta If $f \colon A \to B$, the fibres of $f$ are the sets $f^{-1}(b)$ for $b\in B$.

Comment: Ok, but still I am confused.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I have a problem with the first counterexample there. When one talks of the action of a group $G$ on a topological space $X$, isn't it understood that the maps $x \mapsto gx$ are continuous (and hence homeomorphisms) for all $g\in G$? Otherwise, the group just acts on the underlying set, doesn't it?

Comment: @DanielFischer That's a good point... I actually mixed up my definitions (it's properly discontinuous that implies Hausdorff quotient, and a finite, *continuous* group action is always properly discontinuous).

Comment: Still I am confused on how to prove $X/G$ is Hausdorff. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can use the argument of the answer to [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507755/prove-that-if-g-is-finite-then-any-neighborhood-of-a-g-invariant-subset-of).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. By the way what is the meaning of $P^n$ in this question?

Comment: $P^n$ is presumably real $n$-dimensional projective space $S^n/\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta In fact a more general result is true. If $G$ is compact and $X$ is Hausdorff then $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @DanielFischer Just to confirm, the result in the question statement does not require local-compactness of $X$, right?

Comment: @TheDayBeforeDawn Right. For finite $G$ and Hausdorff $X$ it is straightforward to separate two orbits by disjoint invariant neighbourhoods. First separate them by disjoint neighbourhoods $U$ and $V$ (uses only that $X$ is Hausdorff, and orbits are finite [and disjoint]). Then replace $U$ with $U' = \bigcap_{g \in G} gU$ and analogusly for $V$. Then $U' \cap V' = \varnothing$ since $U' \subset U$, $V' \subset V$, and $U', V'$ are neighbourhoods of the respective orbits because each $gU$ ($gV$) is, and there are only finitely many to intersect.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: given $x \neq y$, try to find neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ such that $GU \cap GV = \emptyset$.